# R: Merging multiple columns into one by group (twice in the same dataframe)

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
      Day HL.Average D.Average LL.Average noHKB.Average    HL.SD      D.SD    LL.SD noHKB.SD
1 0.00000       8760      8900      10000          8030 2337.844  924.2742 1120.785 1592.646
2 1.90625      13300     11900      12100          3860 1016.291 2308.2661 3581.763 1031.057
3 3.00000      14500      7320      12300          1750 2945.098 1308.0389 4338.897 1793.583
4 4.00000      16200      9160      15100          2710 1006.893  514.2177 4362.261 2691.648
```

And I'm trying to organize it into this:

(The numbers in this table is a little different because I made this table in excel instead...)

```
Day Group   Average SD
0   HL  8.76E+03    2337.843612
2   HL  1.33E+04    1016.291341
3   HL  1.45E+04    2945.098059
4   HL  1.62E+04    1006.892976
0   LL  1.00E+04    1120.785009
2   LL  1.21E+04    3581.762692
3   LL  1.23E+04    4338.897375
4   LL  1.51E+04    4362.260616
0   D   8.90E+03    924.2741667
2   D   1.19E+04    2308.266118
3   D   7.32E+03    1308.038881
4   D   9.16E+03    514.2176747
```

I thought about using stack() and then merge(), but the problem is that my original "xx.Average" and "xx.SD" headings complicates the resulting ind from stack...

Does anyone know of a command/way to easily organize the data?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you seen `reshape2`?

Comment: I might consider upvoting as well if the data was reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ananda-mahto's splitstackshape package is designed for this type of problem!

Unfortunately it expects the variable names to be prefixes, rather than postfixes, so we will first need to reverse the variable names

```
library(splitstackshape)
# reverse variable names:
names(df) <- sapply(strsplit(names(df), "\\."), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse="."))
# Reshape the data frame:
newdf <- merged.stack(df, id.vars=c("Day"), var.stubs=c("Average", "SD"), sep=".")
setnames(newdf, ".time_1", "Group")
newdf
##         Day   Group Average        SD
##  1: 0.00000       D    8900  924.2742
##  2: 0.00000      HL    8760 2337.8440
##  3: 0.00000      LL   10000 1120.7850
##  4: 0.00000   noHKB    8030 1592.6460
##  5: 1.90625       D   11900 2308.2661
##  6: 1.90625      HL   13300 1016.2910
##  7: 1.90625      LL   12100 3581.7630
##  8: 1.90625   noHKB    3860 1031.0570
##  9: 3.00000       D    7320 1308.0389
## 10: 3.00000      HL   14500 2945.0980
## 11: 3.00000      LL   12300 4338.8970
## 12: 3.00000   noHKB    1750 1793.5830
## 13: 4.00000       D    9160  514.2177
## 14: 4.00000      HL   16200 1006.8930
## 15: 4.00000      LL   15100 4362.2610
## 16: 4.00000   noHKB    2710 2691.6480
```

Comment: works great! I just went to the original input to change the variable name to make the script even easier. Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't need to reverse the variable names `merged.stack(df, id.vars='Day', var.stubs=c('.Average', '.SD'), sep='var.stubs', atStart=FALSE)`

Answer (score 4):

Here is my clumsy solution. It works but it requires some package (`dplyr` as well for the pipe operator `%>%` but that is just a personal choice.).
It has the `melt` function from the `reshape2` package, the `separate` from `tidyr` to separate columns (for example `LL.Average` into `LL` and `Average`) and the `dcast` from `reshape2` to spread with a formula.
Note that I did not changed the `noHKB` but this might be done with an easy step, it is just a personal choice where to do it.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% melt(id.vars = "Day") %>%
separate(variable, c("Group", "Measure"), sep = "\\.") %>%
dcast(...~ Measure) -> df1
df1

       Day Group Average        SD
1  0.00000     D    8900  924.2742
2  0.00000    HL    8760 2337.8440
3  0.00000    LL   10000 1120.7850
4  0.00000 noHKB    8030 1592.6460
5  1.90625     D   11900 2308.2661
6  1.90625    HL   13300 1016.2910
7  1.90625    LL   12100 3581.7630
8  1.90625 noHKB    3860 1031.0570
9  3.00000     D    7320 1308.0389
10 3.00000    HL   14500 2945.0980
11 3.00000    LL   12300 4338.8970
12 3.00000 noHKB    1750 1793.5830
13 4.00000     D    9160  514.2177
14 4.00000    HL   16200 1006.8930
15 4.00000    LL   15100 4362.2610
16 4.00000 noHKB    2710 2691.6480
```

Comment: @RichardScriven I know. `dplyr` triggers `magrittr` maybe but for just usability I call `dplyr` directly (some times one of its function might be useful even though in this case I used none).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm too much of a newbie to R to understand what you did, and Scott's answer was easier to understand so I went with his. I really appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `devel` version of `data.table` i.e. `v1.9.5` which can take multiple `measure` columns.

We get the `unique` column names of the dataset that are not the 'Day' column and remove the suffix part that starts with `.`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Use `melt` and specify the regex `patterns` in the `measure` argument.  Other options include changing the names of the 'value' and 'variable' columns (`value.name`, `variable.name`).  The 'Group' column by default will be numeric index that can be replaced by the unique names from the earlier step.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
nm1 <- unique(sub('\\..*', '', colnames(df1)[-1]))
melt(setDT(df1), measure=patterns('Average$', 'SD$'), 
    value.name=c('Average', 'SD'), variable.name='Group')[, Group:= nm1[Group]][]
#     Day Group Average        SD
# 1: 0.00000    HL    8760 2337.8440
# 2: 1.90625    HL   13300 1016.2910
# 3: 3.00000    HL   14500 2945.0980
# 4: 4.00000    HL   16200 1006.8930
# 5: 0.00000     D    8900  924.2742
# 6: 1.90625     D   11900 2308.2661
# 7: 3.00000     D    7320 1308.0389
# 8: 4.00000     D    9160  514.2177
# 9: 0.00000    LL   10000 1120.7850
#10: 1.90625    LL   12100 3581.7630
#11: 3.00000    LL   12300 4338.8970
#12: 4.00000    LL   15100 4362.2610
#13: 0.00000 noHKB    8030 1592.6460
#14: 1.90625 noHKB    3860 1031.0570
#15: 3.00000 noHKB    1750 1793.5830
#16: 4.00000 noHKB    2710 2691.6480
```

Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Day = c(0, 1.90625, 3, 4), HL.Average = c(8760L, 
13300L, 14500L, 16200L), D.Average = c(8900L, 11900L, 7320L, 
9160L), LL.Average = c(10000L, 12100L, 12300L, 15100L), 
noHKB.Average =  c(8030L, 
3860L, 1750L, 2710L), HL.SD = c(2337.844, 1016.291, 2945.098, 
1006.893), D.SD = c(924.2742, 2308.2661, 1308.0389, 514.2177), 
LL.SD = c(1120.785, 3581.763, 4338.897, 4362.261), noHKB.SD = c(1592.646, 
1031.057, 1793.583, 2691.648)), .Names = c("Day", "HL.Average", 
"D.Average", "LL.Average", "noHKB.Average", "HL.SD", "D.SD", 
"LL.SD", "noHKB.SD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way making use of `gather`, `separate` and `spread` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
   gather(key, value, -Day) %>%          # gather all columns except "Day" into "key" and "value" columns
   separate(key, c("Group", "tmp")) %>%  # separate the "key" column using "." into "Group", "tmp"
   spread(tmp, value)                    # change "value" column from long to wide format using "tmp"


#       Day Group Average        SD
#1  0.00000     D    8900  924.2742
#2  0.00000    HL    8760 2337.8440
#3  0.00000    LL   10000 1120.7850
#4  0.00000 noHKB    8030 1592.6460
#5  1.90625     D   11900 2308.2661
#6  1.90625    HL   13300 1016.2910
#7  1.90625    LL   12100 3581.7630
#8  1.90625 noHKB    3860 1031.0570
#9  3.00000     D    7320 1308.0389
#10 3.00000    HL   14500 2945.0980
#11 3.00000    LL   12300 4338.8970
#12 3.00000 noHKB    1750 1793.5830
#13 4.00000     D    9160  514.2177
#14 4.00000    HL   16200 1006.8930
#15 4.00000    LL   15100 4362.2610
#16 4.00000 noHKB    2710 2691.6480
```